Why can't I use Text="{Binding City, Source={Binding Address}}"?
Given two models:
public class Person
{
    public Address Address { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; } = null!;
}

And a page:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new Person
        {
            Address = new Address { City = "New York" }
        };
    }
}

<Label Text="{Binding}" BindingContext="{Binding Address.City}" />

The above code works as expected but why can't it be rewritten as follows?
<Label Text="{Binding City, Source={Binding Address}}" />
<Label Text="{Binding}" BindingContext="{Binding City, Source={Binding Address}}" />



why can't it be rewritten as follows?

Binding sources aren't bindable, it's just how it works. However, there's a much simpler way to write it correctly:
<Label Text="{Binding Address.City}" />

